# Aligning text to the right in the C++ console

Tags: c++, text-alignment

How do I format my console output so that it's aligned to the right in C++?

Comment: Place a bunch of spaces in front of your text so that it aligns to the right edge of the 80 column console?  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the manipulator flag `std::right`

[Example](http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060218/cplusplus_streamformatstates_streammanipulators_Page3.html)

or

This works...

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


#include<iomanip>
using std::setw;

int main(){

 int x = 12345;

 cout << "Blah Blah Blah" << endl << setw(80) <<  x << endl;

 system("pause");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ben Voigt, Thanks dude that's why there is an OR in between the two solution options. Read before you comment.

Comment: Ahh, ok: "The adjustfield flag is set to right in standard streams on initialization"

Comment: The example link no longer works, inline the solution in the post or update the link.