# is it possible to make the console output in RTL ( right to left )?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

i want the output from my c++ progrmm to be typed in right to left in the console , i couldn't find and console api function that can help me
( the output is in arabic language this why i want type RTL.

Comment: [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok i will look for it

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio can display Arabic and Hebrew text correctly from right to left.I suggest you could refer to [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/use-bidirectional-languages?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Firstly:

> In order to enter and display bidirectional languages, you must be
>   working with a version of Windows that is configured with the
>   appropriate language. This can either be an English version of Windows
>   with the appropriate language pack installed, or the appropriately
>   localized version of Windows.

I suggest you should set the code page to Arabic code page, or utf8, on your Arabic computer. On non-Arabic computers, it will be difficult to find a console font that can display glyphs.

And then:

> Visual Studio has limited support for right-to-left reading order. By
>   default, text-entry controls in Visual Studio use left-to-right
>   reading order. In most cases, you can use standard Windows gestures to
>   switch reading order.

You could try to press `Ctrl+RightShift` to switch the Properties window to support right-to-left reading order for property values.

> The code editor (and text editor) does not support right-to-left
>   reading order. You can enter text in a bidirectional language, but the
>   reading order is always left-to-right.

As far as I'm concerned, the console does not support Right-To-Left languages.

Comment: that will work for doc, im talking about the cmd ! i want to make it rtl

Comment: For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751827/displaying-arabic-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application/21753872#21753872

Comment: i've already fixed all the problems that faced me with the print arabic ( even the real shape of arabic word ) and i've reverse the output like this man did in this topic , but i want to make the console in rtl so i don't have to reverse the word . thats my whole question about .

Comment: **"i want to make the console in rtl"** If you want to align text to the right in the C++ console? If so,I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824696/aligning-text-to-the-right-in-the-c-console).

Comment: i've seen it before that will align text to the left but still will type it LTR not RTL .

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the console does not support Right-To-Left output. You could try to use [SetConsoleCursorPosition function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to set the cursor position to the far right in the specified console screen buffer. When you enter a character each time, you need to move the cursor one character to the left.

Comment: but that will only go to pos and still the output will be in left no in right

Comment: The console does not support right-to-left output directly. We could implement this function indirectly by writing code that moves the cursor position during output.